# What Linux Distro would your recommend for my Production Web Server?

Tags: linux, debian, httpd

I have been using CentOS for my Web Server for a while now, but it just doesnt feel right any more, I see CentOS as more of an Enterprise Server Distro rather than for HTTPd and FTPd work.

Would your recommend something like Debian? I have used Ubuntu server but it also doesn't feel right. I have heard Debian is pretty good with updates and security so that is why I am leading more towards it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever someone asks me "What Linux distribution should I use?", I tend to reply, "take a look at mirror". It's up to *you*, after all.

- If you need typical enterprise-level boringness with not-ever-changing software versions, pick RHEL/SLES/CentOS.
- If you don't need those enterprise distros but need stability (meaning not often changing software versions) and the latest-and-greatest software is not a necessity, pick Debian.
- If you feel adventurous and need more current software, try Ubuntu Server.
- Other options if you need more current versions and don't care about stability: FreeBSD (with its ports ... though this is usually very stable!), Arch Linux, Gentoo, Debian Sid.

But generally, use the distro you are familiar with. Use your time wisely and install also some other distros, get to know them and see how things are done -> learn something new -> apply that to your knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I understand what you mean by "I tend to reply, "take a look at mirror". It's up to you, after all." I usually do make my own decisions with these types of things but I think I needed to know what other SysAdmins though about it.

Comment: I think I will go with Debian.

Answer (score 3):

You use the distro you're most comfortable with. "Doesn't feel right" is rather vague...if you don't have an actual problem, you don't migrate without testing other platforms for your specific needs. There's not really a huge difference between Apache on distro A and Apache on distro B.

Comment: Thanks, I mainly want to switch because of incompatibility with the software I wish to install.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with CentOS if this is something you have competence on. A simple webserver and/or FTP server requires a low activity of maintenance work, so if you have a setup that works, stick with it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I just need a change, CentOS doesn't appeal to me much any more and I am beginning to have Compatibility issues with software too, thanks for your input.